# Content moderation API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I can't seem to request a trial subscription of the [content moderation API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf753a3f9b070c105bd2c1/operations/57cf753a3f9b070868a1f66e):

Its not listed as a product under 'Request New Trials'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an API key through the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServices).  Content Moderator will appear as one of the API types.  Both free and paid keys are available.